# Getting Unknown error for Internet Service Commands (AT commands)

Tags: gsm, at-command

I am getting unkown errors for AT^SICS=?, here is the procedure I had followed.

```
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"IND airtel",7

OK
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 15,99

OK
AT+CGREG=?
+CGREG: (0-2)

OK
AT+CGREG?
+CGREG: 2,4

OK
AT^SICS=?
+CME ERROR: Unknown
```

is there anything wrong in my procedure.Do I need to do anything else before AT^SICS=? Please let me know,

Thank you,

Comment: You didn't specify the modem model. Anyway, according to the Gemalto AT guide I found, test command should always answer OK (even if the PIN is pending) except in your specific model the command is not supported at all.

Comment: Unrelated: you are out of coverage as stat=4, in `+CGREG`, means _"Unknown, e.g. out of GERAN coverage"_.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni, Thanks for your reply. I am using ELS61 module

Comment: According to ELS61 manual `AT^SICS=?` is supported as well. Are you able to provide any other AT^ command? My guess is that there can be a setting in your terminal using `^` character to escape some special chars. In this case `^S` would be interpreted as a single char (ascii value of 'S' minus 64 = 0×13)

Comment: JRC was not running in the module. So I was getting this issue, now it has been solved thanks for your reply. I have one doubt how to send data to the server using post http.